# My working hours cannot work due to my syntax from database

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I'm really confuse about this syntax. I want to cast my in and out to get the total hours of work but it is not working.

Here's my code:

```
  con.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select name , logdate as 'Date' , min(logtime) as 'IN', max(logtime) as 'OUT'," +
            "CAST(((strftime('%s', max(logtime) ) - strftime('%s', min(logtime) )) % (60 * 60 * 24)) / (60 * 60) AS TEXT) || ':' || " +
            "CAST((((strftime('%s', max(logtime) ) - strftime('%s' , min(logtime) )) % (60 * 60 * 24)) % (60 * 60)) / 60 AS TEXT) as 'workHrs' " +
            "from Attendance1 group by name, logdate order by logdate", con);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(data);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        con.Close();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: For future reference, we very much prefer you put the text of your error messages in your question in place of screen captures.

Comment: `in the local host ?` Basically, this is almost certainly not a C# question. This is a SQL question. There is no point trying to run SQL in C# unless you have verified it already works in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: strftime  ...  should be not a mysql function and || is not used (normally) but concat .. are mixing sqlite function  ??

Answer (score 1):

Your query contains this:

```
CAST(some expression AS TEXT) || ':' || CAST(another expression AS TEXT)
```

But `||` is Oracle string concatenation.  In MySQL use `CONCAT()` instead.

If you look at your error message carefully you'll see that MySQL gacks near the `||`.

It looks like you're trying to use `strftime()` to do time arithmetic. But `strftime()` isn't part of either C# or MySQL.  It looks like you want to know the elapsed time between two `TIME` values, `MAX(logtime)` and `MIN(logtime)`.

You want

```
  TIMEDIFF(MAX(logtime), MIN(logtime))
```

and to format the result nicely as `1:59` you want

```
  DATE_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(MAX(logtime), MIN(logtime)), '%k:%i')
```

**Pro tip**: Bookmark this page on string functions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

And bookmark this page on date/time functions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: sorry i dont familiar with that syntax because im just newb from coding, im just trying but ok i will read about that